# Create keras model from another trained model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to create a new `keras` model from another trained `keras` model

Sample Code for model training referred [from](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-ways-to-create-a-machine-learning-model-with-keras-and-tensorflow-2-0-de09323af4d3):

```
#TF version 2.2.0

from tensorflow.python.keras import models, layers
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python import keras
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import boston_housing
(x_train,y_train), (x_test,y_test) = boston_housing.load_data()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu', input_shape=(13,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size= 64,epochs= 1,validation_split=0.2)
```

Saving the model as `json`

```
json_obj = model.to_json()
new_model = keras.models.model_from_json(json_obj)
```

But after creating the `new_model` the `weights` are different:

```
model.get_weights() != new_model.get_weights()
```

This is the same case if I create `new_model` using `from_config()`. The question is, shouldn't the weight be the same for both `model` and `new_model` as I am creating `new_model` from `model` or my understanding is wrong? Any suggestions are helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_json` doesn't save the model's weights, but only the architecture.

Check here: [to_json method](https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/)

I recommend you to use [save_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/save_model) method.

If you want to copy the model to another directly, do the following:

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model)
new_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())
```

Comment: in that case, can you please explain how does the ```new_model``` get its weights?

Comment: The default one, random initialization as I think.